# Text wont go on the header

Tags: html, css, button, header, href

The href buttons will not go on the header, I have no clue why, please help me out on this. I've tried around with margin-top, but the minimum on that is -14px which isnt enough. I have no clue what other code to use. I am a beginner in css and am still learning.

I want the buttons to be in the middle height of the header, forgot to mention that, sorry.

styles.css

```
    body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
} 

header div, main { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;   
} 

header { 
    background: #d000c2; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
    box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}

header h1 { 
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
} 

main { 
    padding: 21; 
} 

header a { 
    margin-top: -14px;
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white; 
} 

header li {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline; 
    margin-right: -14 px;
    margin-top: 0 px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    z-index: 11;
}

header a:hover {
    border-top: 3px cyan;
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 0px white;
    border-right: 0px white;
    border-left: 0px white;
 }

header li a:hover { 
    color: cyan;
} 

header ul { 
    float: right; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding-top: 1em; 
} 

#vid{
            position:fixed;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            min-width:100%;
            min-height:100%;
            background-size:cover;
            z-index: -1;
            }

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) { 
    header { 
        text-align: center;
        position: relative; 
    } 
    main { 
        padding: 14 px; 
        } 
    header h1 { 
        float: none; 
        margin: 0; 
    } 
    header ul { 
        float: none; 
        margin: 0;
    } 
}
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div>
            <h1><img src=""></h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li>  </li>
                <li><a href="">log-in</a></li>
                <li>  </li>
                <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
                <li>  </li>
                <li><a href="">test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <video autoplay loop id="vid">
            <source src="./videos/background.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>        
    </main> 
</body>
```

Comment: Because you are setting a `height` in the `header`

Comment: Thats because you have a `padding-top: 1em;` for `header ul`..see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0e0xdr29/)

Comment: okay, well that got it onto hte header, but now I want it to be in the heightmiddle of the header

Comment: Can you tell us why you say "I've tried around with margin-top, but the minimum on that is -14px which isnt enough." Maybe it will make sense if you explain.

Comment: I put margin-top: -14 in li but that wont do anything, im probably just dumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0e0xdr29/)

The reason why the `<li>` tags will not go on the header is because of the `1em` `padding-top` applied for `header ul`.

Thus, the new CSS for `header ul` would be like this

```
header ul { 
    float: right; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    /* padding-top: 1em; */ 
}
```

**UPDATE**

To centralize, the links vertically inside the header, you may use flexbox.

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0e0xdr29/2/) that uses

Comment: yeah i fixed that from the comments earlier, but now i want it in the middle height of the header

Comment: And also take a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/0e0xdr29/2/) too..

Comment: The buttons are okay now, but I want them in the right side of the screen, and the picture in the left, which i dont know how to do. :(

Comment: Great.. :).. Glad that it helped.. :)

Comment: Uh, okay, another problem, I cant seem to be able to put the buttons on the right side of the screen, and the picture on the left?

Comment: which picture are you talking about?

Comment: I just have the logo. i removed it from the <img src="">. It's in h1. I want it to be on the left side of the screen.

Comment: That works, cant thank you enough. I spent such a long time searching and looking for the answer to how to put the buttons correctly and you did it in a few minutes, heh, should've came here earlier. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: :D.. Great.. :).. Happy coding.. !!